# BeautifulSoup HTML extract text

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I am working the first time with BeautifulSoup and am trying to extract a joke from a html (which is downloaded). But unfortunately, there are no classes I can use to extract the information.

There is the line "beginning" and "end of the joke" and what I want is the title as well as the text of the joke. Attached you can find my code as well as the output.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('init1.html', 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml')   
    print(soup.prettify)

Output:
<bound method Tag.prettify of <html>
<head>
<title>Joke 1 of 25</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#fddf84" text="black">
<center>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="620">
<td width="470">
<font size="+1"> <br/>
<!--begin of joke -->
A man visits the doctor. The doctor says "I have bad news for you.You have
cancer and Alzheimer's disease". <p>
The man replies "Well,thank God I don't have cancer!"
<!--end of joke -->
</p></font></td></table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
>
```

Comment: did you try xpath?

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and worked:

```py
soup.table.td.text.strip()
# -> 'A man visits the doctor. The doctor says "I have bad news for you.You have\ncancer and Alzheimer\'s disease". \nThe man replies "Well,thank God I don\'t have cancer!"
```